# Guava ImmutableSortedMultiset: how to "sum" two instances?

Tags: java, guava, multiset

I am trying to merge, or "sum", two `SortedMultiset` into one. However, in the `Multisets` class, there is no such method. I would like to do something like:

```
// this is just an example, the actual sets would be created differently (they are NOT empty!)
SortedMultiset<Integer> set1 = ImmutableSortedMultiset.of();
SortedMultiset<Integer> set2 = ImmutableSortedMultiset.of();
SortedMultiset<Integer> sum = Multisets.sum(set1, set2);
```

but this causes:

```
java: incompatible types
required: com.google.common.collect.SortedMultiset<java.lang.Integer>
found:    com.google.common.collect.Multiset<java.lang.Integer>
```

I can do this by changing the type of the two sets as in:

```
Multiset<Integer> set1 = // create the first one...
Multiset<Integer> set2 = // create the second one...
Multiset<Integer> sum = Multisets.sum(set1,set2); // does NOT work
SortedMultiset<Integer> sortedSum = ImmutableSortedMultiset.copyOf(sum.iterator());
```

I was wondering if there was a way to achieve this more elegantly and most of all by using `SortedMultiset` instances directly as in the first example.

**EDIT**:

The part I was missing was that this line:

```
SortedMultiset<Integer> sum = Multisets.sum(set1, set2);
```

Should be:

```
SortedMultiset<Integer> sortedSum = ImmutableSortedMultiset.copyOf(Multisets.sum(set1, set2));
```

Comment: In what way does `ImmutableSortedMultiset.copyOf(Multisets.sum(set1, set2))` not work?

Comment: From your edit, it looks like that version does work; you'd just like a more elegant version with an overload of `Multisets.sum`?

Comment: Yes! Sorry, `copyOf` __does__ work. I wanted to avoid the copy though. It's been a long day of work and I am getting confused :/

Comment: There's currently no way to do that, then.  Why not file a feature request?

Comment: Done. It would be convenient to exploit tricks used for regular `Multiset`s, i.e., returning views where possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Louis is absolutely right, `Multisets.sum(set1, set2)` certainly does work, nor does copying to an `ImmutableSortedMultiset` cause any trouble.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    final SortedMultiset<Integer> set1 = ImmutableSortedMultiset.of(1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3);
    final SortedMultiset<Integer> set2 = ImmutableSortedMultiset.of(1, 1, 2, 4);
    final SortedMultiset<Integer> sum = ImmutableSortedMultiset.copyOf(Multisets.sum(set1, set2));
    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

outputs:

```
[1 x 3, 2 x 3, 3 x 3, 4]
```

I suspect that it is the piece you have redacted, and replaced with `ImmutableSortedMultiset.of();` that is giving you trouble. But I cannot comment too much there as you've neglected to share it.

Comment: Your code is different than mine. I haven't spotted the problem before but it's clear: `Multisets.sum()` returns a `Multiset`, not a `SortedMultiset`, hence copying in the `SortedMultiset` does the trick. So there is no omission on my part. I guess my assumption was that it would be possible to __avoid__ the copy all together.

Comment: Note that simply calling `Multisets.sum()` does _not_ return a _sorted_ `Multiset`: if you swap the arguments and do `Multisets.sum(set2, set1)`, you get `[1 x 3, 2 x 3, 4, 3 x 3]`.